# Как одновременно вводить и выводить данные в консоль python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

Я даже не знаю ка сформулировать вопрос, что бы он был ясен, но все таки постараюсь. В итоге я хочу сделать свой мини-чат - я могу получать новые сообщения во время ввода своего текста сообщения.

Мне нужен способ сделать одновременный ввод и вывод в консоли. Я пробовал делать так: с помощью ESC-последовательностей, двигать строку с вводом, затем перемещаться выше, выводить в освободившуюся строку текст, а потом возвращаться назад на строку вниз, где идет введенный мной текст и приглашение ввода. Это оказалось очень неэффективным и неудобным кодом, так как приглашение и текст пропадали, когда я пытаюсь вставить строку, когда окно консоли уже подошло к концу. Так же были проблемы, что если выводится несколько строк на экран, то сдвигалось все только на одну строку, и я писал ввод уже вдоль выведенного текста. Я пока что пользуюсь решением получать данные только по окончании ввода, но хотелось бы, что бы я мог получать нужную информация прямо во время ввода.

Возможно, как предложил @andreymal, стоит сделать 2 секции - внизу ввод, сверху вывод, но я не представляю как, я слышал что есть curses, но только на линукс. Есть ли какие то еще варианты с готовыми решениями, или стоит продолжить искать решение с ESC-последовательностями?

Comment: после "Мне нужен способ сделать одновременный ввод и вывод в консоли" желательно описать зачем это и что в итоге вы хотите увидеть?

Comment: @Jack_oS чтобы внизу терминала была строка ввода input(), а вверху над вводом параллельно из другого потока выводился какой-нибудь лог, при этом не мешая вводу внизу. Если сделать простой print одновременно с input, то он перекроет собой ввод и всё станет выглядеть коряво, поэтому и нужно возиться с ESC-последовательностями

Comment: На сайте уже был подобный вопрос, но что-то я его не могу найти...

Comment: Зачем вам это нужно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что ты имеешь в виду под консолью python? Если запущенный скрипт в командной строке windows, то можно так, с кареткой и самописным input'ом. Это довольно просто и работает. Из этого кода будет ясен принцип.

```
import msvcrt
import time
 

def input_wait(prompt='', timeout=1000, *, _delay=0.02):
    inpute_line = str()
    start = time.time()
 
    while time.time() - start < timeout:
        prompt_t = '\r{:.1f}| {}{}'.format(timeout - time.time() + start,
                                           prompt, inpute_line)
        print(prompt_t, end='')
        
        if msvcrt.kbhit():
            char = msvcrt.getwch()
            if char == '\r':
                msvcrt.putwch('\n')
                break
            elif char == '\000' or char == '\xe0':
                msvcrt.getwch()
                pass
            elif ord(char) == 8: # backspace
                print('\r{}'.format(' ' * len(prompt_t)), end='')
                inpute_line = inpute_line[:-1]
            else:
                inpute_line += char
        else:
            time.sleep(_delay)
    else:
        inpute_line = None
    
    return inpute_line
 
timeout = 10
prompt = 'Enter answer: '
 
print('Сколько будет 5 + 5?')
print('у вас есть 10 секунд')
 
while True:
    answer = input_wait(prompt, timeout=timeout)
    
    if answer is None:
        print('\nTime is up')
    else:
        if answer == '10':
            print("It's right answer!")
        elif answer == 'q':
            print('exit...')
            break        
        else:
            print("No! Try again.")
```

Насколько я понял, тебе нужно перерисовывать не одну строчку, а несколько. Вот код, который демонстрирует свободное перемещение курсора для перерисовки кареткой.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import colorama
from time import sleep

colorama.init()

# # ESC [ n A       # move cursor n lines up
# # ESC [ n B       # move cursor n lines down

cursor_up = lambda lines: '\x1b[{0}A'.format(lines)
cursor_down = lambda lines: '\x1b[{0}B'.format(lines)


print("meow :)")
print("meow-meow :)")
print("meow-meow-meow :)")
lines_up = 3
print(cursor_up(lines_up), end='')
sleep(1)
print("woof", " " * 10)
sleep(1)
lines_down = 1
sleep(1)
print(cursor_down(lines_down), end='')
sleep(1)
print("woof-woof-woof", " " * 10)
sleep(1)
lines_up = 2
sleep(1)
print(cursor_up(lines_up), end='')
print("woof-woof", " " * 10)
sleep(1)
```

С этим пониманием можно свободно выводить в командной строке какую угодно информацию на множестве строк, постоянно обновлять её и одновременно писать в свой input.