# Python CLI Ввод всегда внизу терминала

Tags: python, консоль

##### Контекст

Я выполняю вузовский проект по написанию чата на сокетах.
Клиентская часть запущена в GNOME Shell.
Python 3.8
Приложение многопоточное

##### Проблема

Пока клиент ожидает ввода сообщения от других пользователей прилетают и из-за этого ломается внешний вид.
Вот минимальный пример для воспроизведения проблемы:

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep
def spam():
    for i in range(50):
        print(i)
        sleep(1)
thread = Thread(target=spam, daemon=True)
thread.start()

text = input('Give me some input: ')
print('You said: %s' % text)
```

Хочется чтобы ввод всегда оставался внизу окна терминала. Смотрел в сторону многих библиотек, но по тем было так мало примеров, что чтобы разобраться прийдется воротить библиотеку от начала и до конца. Очень жду минимальный рабочий пример (возможно с использованием любых библиотек в пределах разумного). Заранее спасибо.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1243530

Comment: ну а библиотеки типа curses вас никак не спасут?