# Параллельный ввод и и вывод данных в консоль python

Tags: python, консоль, вывод, ввод

Столкнулся с проблемой, что хотелось бы одновременно вводить и выводить данные из консоли python. Порылся на stackoverflow, всё что нашёл, так это таймауты для ввода. Такое мне не особо подошло, нужно чтобы всё параллельно работало в одну секунду. Если есть возможность, то объясните как это сделать, или если уже такой вопрос проскакивал, скиньте ссылку.

Заранее спасибо

Comment: Вы бы конкретизировали ситуацию. Но в целом, при блокирующих операциях ввода-вывода - асинхронный режим, при блокирующих - многопоточный. В документации есть описание и того и другого.

Comment: Не знаю как конкретизировать. Есть ли какие то методы, которые встроенную функцию input() могли бы пропустить?

Comment: полагаю, и асинхронка и многопоточность это должны обеспечить. Но не пробовал. Подумайте также,  нужен ли вам `input ()` с его плюшками или `sys.stdin()` достаточно (этот без плюшек, но побыстрее будет).

Comment: Вопрос задавался неоднократно. Быстро нашел вот: [Как одновременно вводить и выводить данные в консоль python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1243530/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c-python)

Comment: Сергей, в принципе без разницы, просто мне не хватает знаний для таких вот вещей. Благодарю за помощь.

Comment: Роман, тут как раз таки таймаут для ввода. В целом это для меня тоже полезная штука, но хотелось бы именно потоково вводить и выводить одновременно данные.